# Список последних десяти сообщений

Tags: java

Мне нужен некий "кеш", который хранит десять последних сообщений. Такой "кеш" должен хорошо справляться с высокой нагрузкой и многопоточностью. Почему-то в голову сразу приходит такой костыльный вариант:

```
public class LastMessagesDemo {

    private static int SIZE = 10;
    private String[] messages = new String[SIZE];

    public synchronized void addMessage(String msg) {
        String[] newMessages = new String[SIZE];
        System.arraycopy(messages, 0, newMessages, 1, SIZE - 1);
        messages = newMessages;
        messages[0] = msg;
    }

    public synchronized List<String> getLastMessages() {
        return Arrays.asList(messages);
    }
}
```

Подходит ли такое решение под работу с большой нагрузкой в многопоточном режиме? Может быть есть какие-то стандартные (уже написанные) решения?

Comment: если ничего более дельного не посоветуют, можно сделать `messages` `volatile`, присваивание `messages = newMessages` сделать последней операцией и убрать `synchronized` с `getLastMessages()`.

Comment: кого у вас больше, читателей или писателей?

Comment: Писателей гораздо больше :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Почему бы не использовать один массив, перезаписывая один (самый старый) элемент при добавлении нового циклическим образом?

Потребуется только поддерживать актуальный индекс элемента, ожидающего замены `Current` (и количество сообщений на то время, пока сообщений меньше десяти).

Запись ведётся в ячейку с индексом `Current`, после чего этот индекс инкрементируется

```
 Current = (Current + 1) % SIZE
```

При требовании получения списка в порядке свежести используется цикл по индексам

```
for (i = 0; i < Count; i++)
{
   output String[(Current + SIZE - i - 1) % SIZE];
}
```